# Create a TextBlock for every item in a List<Object>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Currently I'm trying to create a TextBlock for every object in a provided list. The object is of type person with various fields, but I'm wanting to display their full name as the content for the TextBlock. I'm doing this like so:

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GetPeople}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This gets the correct values for every object in the list, however, when I add a new object to the list, it does not show up until I reload the control.

Comment: Don't use `List<Object>`. Use `ObservableCollection<Object>`. ObservableCollection raises an event (`CollectionChanged`) when an item is added, removed, or replaced. List doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ObservableCollection<T>`, `BindingList<T>`, or another collection that can raised events.